# Pandas dataframes: Adding columns with percentage for rows starting with the same string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
     1995  1996
AT1     3     6
AT2     5     3
AT3     2     1
FR1     1     1
FR5     2     1
FR7     7     8
```

I would like to add columns or create a dataframe containing the percentage of each row over the total, depending on the groups indicated by the first two letters.
Basically, for each column:

- Sum the values of each group of rows (i.e sum all the rows starting
  by AT,  then all the rows starting with FR...).
- Divide each row in the different groups by its sum and multiply by
  100.
- Put these values in a new column or a new dataframe.

The expected output would be:

```
     1995  1996  Percentage_1995  Percentage_1996
AT1     3     6               30               60
AT2     5     3               50               30
AT3     2     1               20               10
FR1     1     1               10               10
FR5     2     1               20               10
FR7     7     8               70               80
```

I know it may sound confusing so I apologize if I'm not very clear. I would appreciate any help you could provide. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy.transform` with `df.div` to divide and `df.mul` to multiply by 100 then use `df.assign`

```
temp = df.div(
    df.groupby(df.index.str[:2]).transform("sum")
).mul(100).add_prefix("Percentage")

df.assign(**temp)
    1995  1996  Percentage1995  Percentage1996
AT1     3     6            30.0            60.0
AT2     5     3            50.0            30.0
AT3     2     1            20.0            10.0
FR1     1     1            10.0            10.0
FR5     2     1            20.0            10.0
FR7     7     8            70.0            80.0
```